# EXCEL VBA: ConvertFormula returns #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

I have several subroutines that use the ConvertFormula VBA command.  Unfortunately I ran into a situation where none of the subroutines work.  It appears it is the single line containing the `ConvertFormula` command that is returning the `#VALUE` error so I can't error check any deeper than that.

Using the Immediate window I was able to test this isolated command.  Here are 3 separately executed lines of code.

```
ActiveSheet.range("Z270")=application.ConvertFormula(formula:="=Sheet2!V23+Sheet2!W23*Z$224+Sheet2!X23*Z$224^2+Sheet2!Y23*Z$224^3+Sheet2!Z23*Z$224^4",fromreferencestyle:=xlA1, toreferencestyle:=xla1, toabsolute:=xlabsolute)

ActiveSheet.range("Z270")=application.ConvertFormula(formula:="=Sheet2!V23+Sheet2!W23*Z$224+Sheet2!X23*Z$224^2+Sheet2!Y23*Z$224^3",fromreferencestyle:=xlA1, toreferencestyle:=xla1, toabsolute:=xlabsolute)

ActiveSheet.range("Z270")=application.ConvertFormula(formula:="=Sheeet2!V23+Sheeet2!W23*Z$224+Sheeet2!X23*Z$224^2+Sheeet2!Y23*Z$224^3",fromreferencestyle:=xlA1, toreferencestyle:=xla1, toabsolute:=xlabsolute)
```

The first line returned `#VALUE`, the 2nd returned the formula correctly, and the 3rd returned `#VALUE`  again.  Notice that in the 3rd I'd renamed the offsheet reference to `Sheeet2`, with an extra 'e' to add length to the formula.

I suspect that the behavior is related only to the formula string length and not the contents.  The formula string lengths in my example are 85, 66, and 70 characters for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd lines respectively.

I'm not sure where the exact cut-off is, or whether the `$` is excluded from the character count limit.  Just wanted to put this out there to see if anyone can confirm my hypothesis, provide further insight, or provide an alternative explanation.

In response to the RFI about reference cell values, all referenced cells contained numeric values.  'Z$224' value was 65, formatted as 65.0.  Sheet2 cells V23 thru Z23 had the following values (formatted in scientific notation):
1.0037243; -0.000062039288; 0.000000012983893; -0.00000000042225392

Comment: `toreferencestyle:=x1a1` should be `toreferencestyle:=xla1` you have a `1` in place of the lowercase `L`

Comment: Thanks Scott.  That was a typo that didn't exist in my original subs, but it did exist in the immediate window tests I ran.  Oddly enough the typo didn't affect the results of my test.  Not sure if I got lucky, or if Microsoft allows that intentionally to help out sloppy coders.  I'll fix the typo though.

Comment: According to [MSDN Application.ConvertFormula Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822751.aspx) "There is a 255 character limit for the formula". Can you also include the values for the reference cells?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same with varying character limits. Have not found a fix but there are workarounds.

1. Shorten the formulas using `Custom user functions`
2. Write your own conversion function. Which you can use `Regular Expression` to insert dollar signs to references and simple `Replace()` to remove them.

Comment: Footnote: using regular expression Replace will require you to insert a intermediate character since dollar sign is reserved and can't be escaped.